# why the extra 10 pixels in this JSfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

Can someone tell me why I have to subtract an extra 10 pixels from the positioning in this JSFiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/MPFyt/

Comment: It's likely jsFiddle's (stupid) CSS reset. Click the "Normalized CSS" checkbox to turn it off.

Comment: Thanks guys...Learned something today.  +1 all around.

Comment: @matt Yep I know, but you have to wait 5 minutes so that's what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the jsfiddle window has 10px of padding around it.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the CSS reset that's tripping you up. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/YQPsz/